# How to set a complete image as a button in an UIITabBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I was wondering how one could completely replace a `UITabBar` button completely as an image (i.e. without any text below the image, similar to the style found in Instagram or Polar).

I have tried using `[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option1Selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option1.png"]];` as suggested in this [guide](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/), but it still includes the text in the bottom. Help is appreciated - thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Have you looked at the UITabBarItem method, initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `edge insets` and use different `image rendering options` in `iOS 7` and later versions. I used a simple `OS_version check` and implemented it as follows:

Define a constant for `OS_version` check:

```
#define DEVICE_SYSTEM_VERSION [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]
```

Then used the following piece of code in your base viewController:

```
UIImage *yourSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option1Selected.png"];
UIImage *yourUnSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option1.png"];

viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

if (DEVICE_SYSTEM_VERSION >= 7) 
{
    [yourViewController.tabBarItem setImage:[yourUnSelectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [yourViewController.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[yourSelectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
} 
else 
{
    [yourViewController.tabBarItem setImage:yourUnSelectedImage];
    [yourViewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:yourSelectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:image];
}


// set the title to be an empty string
yourViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"";

// set edge insets so that the image occupies the entire area
if (DEVICE_SYSTEM_VERSION <= 7) 
{
    yourViewController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 0, -8, 0);
}
else
{
    yourViewController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps! :)